# How to get current Controller & Action in controller

Tags: lumen-5.3

How can I get current controller & action in Lumen

Let say I have a User resource in the routing.
Then if I access the `user/show/id`, can I get the current controller name & action name in the Controller?

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         $controllerName = ???;
         $actionName = ??? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one simple trick to get action and controller name**

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_request = app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
    list($controllerName ,$actionName)=explode('@',$this->_request->route()[1]['uses']);
    print_r($controllerName);
    print_r($actionName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you will have Action and Controller name (just name with no route):

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        list($controllerName, $actionName) = explode('@', substr(strrchr($request->route()[1]['uses'], '\\'), 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***I have used and checked in Laravel / Lumen 8 version to get controller and action name in controller***:

```
public function getControllerActionName(){
        $this->_request = app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
        list($controllerName ,$actionName) = explode('@',$this->_request->route()[1]['uses']);
        $controllerName = strtolower(str_replace("App\Http\Controllers\\",'',$controllerName));
        $actionName = strtolower($actionName);
        return array('controller' => $controllerName, 'action' => $actionName);
    }
```

It worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: You can see result it by calling this function in any controller's action eg. print_r($this->getControllerActionName()); which will result you like Array
(
    [controller] => userscontroller
    [action] => getprofiledetail
)